# preg_match php problem

Tags: php, preg-match

i try to find a Link i a page

Link looks like this

```
https://pos.xxxxxxxxxx.de/xxxxxxxxxxxx/app?funnel=login_box&tid=2001004
```

i hide the domain :)

So there is my code:

```
preg_match('~(https://pos.xxxxxxxxxx.de/xxxxxxxxxx/app\?funnel=login_box&tid=\d+)~', $text, $ans);
```

nothing found...

i try this one

```
preg_match('~(https://pos.xxxxxxxxxx.de/xxxxxxxxxx/app\?funnel=login_box&tid=)~', $text, $ans);
```

try to find only the fixed part of the link...

stil nothing

so i try this one

```
preg_match('~(https://pos.xxxxxxxxxx.de/xxxxxxxxxx/app\?funnel=login_box)~', $text, $ans);
```

now i find some links, but why i can't find the whole link???

Comment: You need to provide the source of the page you're searching in, otherwise this question can not be answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably in html source, `&` is expanded to `&amp;`, try:

```
&(amp;)?
```

Just reminder - `.` means every char, so you should escape it, but it's not important here.

Answer (score 0):

preg_match("/(https://[^=]+=[^=]+=[\d]+)/i",$text,$m);

if you have ' or " in the end of link, smth like this href="https://....."

you can use this one: preg_match("/\"(https://[^\"]+)\"/i",$text,$m);

Answer (score 0):

```
$html = "http://www.scroogle.org
http://www.scroogle.org/
http://www.scroogle.org/index.html
http://www.scroogle.org/index.html?source=library
You can surf the internet anonymously at https://ssl.scroogle.org/cgi-bin/nbbwssl.cgi.";

preg_match_all('/\b((?P<protocol>https?|ftp):\/\/(?P<domain>[-A-Z0-9.]+)(?P<file>\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|!:,.;]*)?(?P<parameters>\?[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|!:,.;]*)?)/i', $html, $urls, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
$urls = $urls[1][0];
```

Will **match**:

**http://www.scroogle.org**

**http://www.scroogle.org/**

**http://www.scroogle.org/index.html**

**http://www.scroogle.org/index.html?source=library**

You can surf the internet anonymously at **https://ssl.scroogle.org/cgi-bin/nbbwssl.cgi**.

To **loop results** you can use:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($urls[0]); $i++) {
    echo $urls[1][$i]."\n";
}
```

will output:

http://www.scroogle.org
http://www.scroogle.org/
http://www.scroogle.org/index.html
http://www.scroogle.org/index.html?source=library
https://ssl.scroogle.org/cgi-bin/nbbwssl.cgi

cheers, Lob